# How do I display a dynamic image on a template, when the function to create the image requires arguments, like a list of coordinates..?

Tags: django

***Problem in short:***

How do I display a dynamic image on a template, when the function to create the image requires arguments, like an arbitrary long list of coordinates..?

for example `<img src="{% url getComplexImg coords %}"/>`, where coords is a list of arbitrary length consisting of either integers or tuples of integers, and getComplexImg is a view which returns an image as HttpResponse where mimetype is image/png, and where the image is generated with the list of coordinates.

**EDIT:** I have added a solution (inspired by the first answer) to the bottom.

***The problem, long version***

Following is a simplification of what I'm trying to do

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^getSimpleImg$', views.getSimpleImg, name='getSimpleImg'),
    url(r'^getComplexImg$', views.getComplexImg, name='getComplexImg'),
    url(r'^showAllImgs$', views.showAllImgs, name='showAllImgs')
    )
```

views.py:

```
...
from django.template import Context, loader
...

def getSimpleImg(request):
    return HttpResponse(getImg.simple(), mimetype="image/png")

def getComplexImg(request, coords_1, coords_2):
    return HttpResponse(getImg.complex(coords_1,coords_2), mimetype="image/png")

def showAllImgs(request):
    coords_1, coords_2 = data_module.get_all_coordinates()
    context = Context({
        'coords_1':coords_1,
        'coords_2':coords_2})
    template = loader.get_template('showall.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

'data_module.get_all_coordinates()' is just a method which returns two lists of arbitrary length (the lists could contain either integers or tuples of integers).

showall.html:

```
<html>
...
<img src="{% url getSimpleImg %}"/>
<img src="{% url getComplexImg coords_1 coords_2 %}"/>
...
</html>
```

It is very easy to make Django display the image returned from 'getSimpleImg', because it doesn't need any list arguments. But I'm struggling to make Django display the complex image, because I down't know how to pass on an arbitrary list as argument from the template.

The code above obviously doesn't work because Django can't lookup '{% url getComplexImg coords_1 coords_2 %}' in the urls.py.

**How should this kind of problem be solved?**

Should I for example somehow send the images with the context? like:

views.py:

```
...
def showAllImgs(request):
coords_1, coords_2 = data_module.get_all_coordinates()
context = Context({
    'img_1':getImg.simple(),
    'img_2':getImg.complex(coords_1,coords_2)})
template = loader.get_template('showall.html')
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

showall.html:

```
<html>
...
<img src="{{ img_1 }}"/>
<img src="{{ img_2 }}"/>
...
</html>
```

(above doesn't work, it's just to illustrate what I mean)

OR should I somehow import all the stuff I need into the template and then create and display images from there..? like:

showall.html:

```
{% import data_module %}
{% import getImg %}
<html>
...
<img src="{% getImg.simple() %}"/>
<img src="{% getImg.complex(data_module.get_all_coordinates()) %}"/>
...
</html>
```

## Solution, inspired by first answer

I am solving it for now by passing on the context as:

`Context({'coords_1':"_".join([str(v) for v in coords_1])})`

and catching the url in urls.py with :

`url(r'^getComplexImg/(?P<coords_1>[0-9_\-]+)/$', views.getComplexImg, name='getComplexImg')`

And in my getComplexImg view, I convert the stringed lists back to real lists with:

```
coords_1 = [int(v) for v in coords_1.split('_')]
```

*It works and I am satisfied for now, but I have a bad feeling that this might not be the most optimal solution*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though your `urls.py` is malformed.

You can pass variables via your urls. By using the correct syntax (the variables as regexs) you can refer to these variables when calling the `url()` or `{% url %}`, as you are trying to do.

This simple example comes from here: 
http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter08.html#using-default-view-arguments

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^blog/$', views.page),
    (r'^blog/page(?P<num>\d+)/$', views.page),
)
```

views.py

```
def page(request, num='1'):
    # Output the appropriate page of blog entries, according to num.
    # ...
```

The bit that matters here is: **`(?P<num>\d+)`**

You can then pass whatever is in the `<here>` to your view function, eg: `def my_view(request, here): ...`

In your case you would replace the following:

```
url(r'^getSimpleImg$', views.getSimpleImg, name='getSimpleImg'),
...
```

To something like this:

```
url(r'^getSimpleImg/(?P<coord1>\d+)/(?P<coord2>\d+)/$', views.getSimpleImg, name='getSimpleImg'),
...
```

You many not want to use named variables in your urls, but should that be the case you cannot use `{% url %}` either and would need to find another solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. But how would you solve it if coord1 is an arbitrary long list of integers or tuples of integers.?

Comment: As your view is just a python function you are able to parse that variable however you would like. A data mining friend of mine uses underscores as a separator in his urls for example. In that case this would work: `Img/1_2_3_4/1234/` and parsed in python: `c1 = coord1.split("_")`.